# Can UglifyJS keep line breaks and remove comments only?

Tags: uglifyjs

We would like to use UglifyJS to only remove comments but preserve everything else, is this possible?

AFAIK `beautify` is the only option that adds line breaks, but it does not match with our dev's source and it can get difficult to debug for QA purposes.

Thanks.